# opening a new web form in a jquery mobile panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel

I am trying to open a new web form in a Jquery Mobile panel. I am trying to open  a panel on webform3.aspx and trying to call a new web form called webform2.aspx from webform3.aspx. Below is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
      <title>Panel</title>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

          <div id="languagePanel" class="ss-panel-language ui-panel ui-panel-position-right ui-panel-display-overlay ui-panel-closed ui-body-inherit ui-panel-fixed ui-panel-animate" data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true">
           <div class="ui-panel-inner"><div id="languagePanelInternal" class="ss-panel-language-internal"></div></div>
        </div>
         

          <a href="#languagePanel" class="ss-header-actions-language ui-link">
              test
         </a>
         
        <script>

var languageUrl = "WebForm2.aspx";
            $("#languagePanel").on("panelbeforeopen", function () {
                $("#languagePanelInternal").load(languageUrl, function () {
                    $("#languagePanelInternal").trigger("create");
                    $("#languagePanel").trigger("updatelayout");
                    $.mobile.activePage.trigger("pagecreate");
                });
            });
        </script>
    

     
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

on WebForm2.aspx, I just have two simple radio buttons and a submit button, below is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div >
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbEng" runat="server" Text="English" GroupName="lang"   />
             <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbspan" runat="server" Text="Español" GroupName="lang"  />
        </div>
        <div >
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click"   />
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Panel on webform3.aspx works fine and the radio button also displays well, but when I click on submit button, nothing happens. The code does not go to code behind. The code behind for submit button is like so:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (rdbEng.Checked == true)
            {
                Session["language"] = "en-US";


            }
            else if (rdbspan.Checked == true)
            {
                Session["language"] = "es-MX";


            }
        }
```

Below is the screenshot of what I am seeing and clicking on submit button does not do anything. I want the control to go Submit_Click event when the submit button is clicked.

[image]

Comment: any help or hint will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQM Panel is expecting some markup, not a whole HTML page.

So, The jQuery `load` needs the correct selector for that:

`var languageUrl = "WebForm2.aspx #form1"`;

Here is the jQuery documentation: [jQuery .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

I strongly believe You need also to double-check Your page markup and how You are invoking the enhancement of the panel.

Avoid to use twice the `id` *form1* inside `WebForm2.aspx`, and fill Your panel just only with the **content** that You need (i.e. the radio buttons).

Moreover, I believe Your JavaScript code is for an old JQM version. For JQM 1.4.5 `$("#languagePanelInternal").enhanceWithin();` will suffice.